# Customize ApplicationMenu button in Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi

Tags: delphi, ribbon

Does anyone know how to change the 'File' label of the Application Menu in the [Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi](https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework)?

Comment: Very good question. I spent a bit of time trying to work this out, without success. I have a feeling that the system doesn't offer you any way to customise this.