# Localization of "File" and recent items title

Tags: delphi, windows-ribbon-framework

I'm using the [Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/RibbonFramework) in a Delphi XE4 project, on a Windows 10 machine. I already have a TActionList and each TAction's Caption is set in code depending on the selected language for my application. I noticed that by linking a TAction with a TUICommand, almost all captions change, except for the **Application Menu** (normally "File" or "Fichier" in my case) and the recent items title (always retains value set in the markup).

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588413/customize-applicationmenu-button-in-windows-ribbon-framework-for-delphi?r=SearchResults&s=2|132.0471), but no answer was provided.

I tried setting the caption of the command directly, associating a TAction and changing its caption like the others, associating the action list with the ribbon (ActionManager property) and making sure the ribbon commands and TAction have the same name, calling `TUIRibbon.InvalidateUICommand`, nothing worked.

From what I gather in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-controls-applicationmenu), the application menu seems to be tightly coupled with the operating system. But at the very least, I expected to be able to somehow change the recent items title.

Any help would be appreciated.